# Select nth columns of an ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have the following 4D numpy array:

```
X = np.random.randint(0,9,(10,1,5,4))
```

So for example,

```
X[0]
array([[[0, 6, 7, 7],
        [8, 3, 8, 8],
        [1, 4, 1, 0],
        [2, 4, 6, 0],
        [8, 3, 7, 8]]])
```

And

```
X[1]
array([[[3, 4, 3, 6],
        [1, 2, 1, 5],
        [1, 1, 0, 7],
        [2, 5, 6, 2],
        [4, 2, 6, 0]]])
```

Each column represents a particular quantity.
But I am interested in a subarray, containing only the first columns of `X`, such that:

```
X_sub[0] =
array([[[0],
        [8],
        [1],
        [2],
        [8]]])
```

And

```
X_sub[1] =
array([[[3],
        [1],
        [1],
        [2],
        [4]]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get what you are asking for you have access the `X` `np.ndarray` as

```
X_sub[i] = X[i, :, :, 0]  
# i-th subarray, select full 1d subarray, select all rows, select first column
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer helps. I get it using `X_sub = X[:, :, :, 0]`

Answer (score 0):

```py
a = ([[[0, 6, 7, 7],
        [8, 3, 8, 8],
        [1, 4, 1, 0],
        [2, 4, 6, 0],
        [8, 3, 7, 8]]])
        
req_list= []
for x in a[0]:
    temp=x[0]
    req_list.append(temp)
```